# Class data member struct : accessing struct members

Tags: c++, class, struct, member

I have created a simple class called Foo, which contains a data member, Bar, which is a struct.

```
class Foo
{
  public :
  struct Bar {
    int a;
  };
};
```

I'd like to be able to access members in the struct either from functions I define in the class, or from the driver file, but I'm not sure how. Note: I've declared Bar as a public member because I am trying to access the members directly without using a get function. There is method in my madness, but I'll get to that later, so please accept that I want the struct to be public for now.

This is a very stripped down version of a larger program, so please forgive the simplicity.

Comment: `Bar` is not a data member, it is a class definition. You need something like `Bar bar;` to have `bar` as a member of `Foo`

Answer (score 0):

> I have created a simple class called Foo, which contains a data member, Bar, which is a struct.

Not really. `Foo` doesn't contain any data members at all. It just defines a type called `Foo::Bar`.  An object of type `Foo::Bar` has an `int` data member named `a`, but a `Foo` object itself doesn't have any `Bar` or `int` subobjects.

If you do want an object of type `Bar` in every `Foo`, you need to declare that member with some name:

```
class Foo
{
  public :
  struct Bar {
    int a;
  };
  Bar bar;
};
```

This would let you do things like:

```
void test() {
    Foo f;
    f.bar.a = 5;
}
```

Comment: I realised about 10 seconds after I posted my message that I had made that mistake :/ Thank you, I feel quite dumb.